# c++ | Не работает функция

Tags: c++, строки

Ничего не возвращает, как исправить?
Должна вернуть ту строку что получает, но ту часть что идёт от индекса разрезанную по индексу. Короче отрезает кусок строки

```
    string mb_substr(string text, int ind) {
int text_size = text.length();
string new_text;
for (int i = ind; i < text_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < text_size - ind; j++) {
        new_text[j] = text[i];
    }
}
return new_text;
}
//Вызов функции - cout << mb_substr("dsakodaskoda", 7) << endl;
```

Comment: return text.substr (ind); Удалить for ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Когда вы делаете вот так:

```
new_text[j] = text[i];
```

Размер вашего `std::string` не меняется, поэтому, когда вы возвращаете его из функции, он имеет размер 0, в результате чего вам выводится пустая строка. Для использования данной конструкции вы можете указать размер при создании, заполнив строку мусором:

```
std::string new_text(text_size - ind, ' ');
```

Но ещё лучше будет зарезервировать ожидаемое место и заполнять строку методом `push_back` (или аналогичными конструкциями напр. `+=`):

```
std::string new_text;
new_text.reserve(text_size - ind);
for (int i = ind; i < text_size; i++) {
    new_text.push_back(text[i]);
}
```

**2.** Вам не нужен второй цикл. Если бы строки работали так, как вы предполагали, то каждый символ ожидаемого результата поочерёдно полностью заполнял бы собой результирующую строку, что вам не нужно.

**3.** Как отметил комментатор выше, в `std::string` уже есть метод который делает то, что вам нужно:

```
  std::string("dsakodaskoda").substr(7);
```

Или в функции:

```
std::string mb_substr(const std::string& text, int ind) {
    return text.substr(ind);
}
```